# call method of child from instance of type Parent

Tags: java, object

I have to make the following equals method:

```
public boolean equals(ParentClass pa) {
    if (!(pa instanceof ChildClass))
        return false;
    boolean sameID = ID.equals(pa.getID());
    return super.equals(pa) && sameID;
}
```

The class ChildClass is a child of the class ParentClass, and this would be it's equals method. The method getId() is only in the ChildClass, but I need to know how to get the method pa.getID() to work, is there any way to do a cast here? since i get an error, the compiler can't be sure if pa is an instance of Child or not.

This is the erro that i get:

```
Error:(19, 73) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getID()
  location: variable pa of type ParentClass
```

I need the method to be of type ParentClass, because the function should return false when an object of type ParentClass instead of an error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the complete error in the stack trace.

Comment: sure, already edited the question

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: `equals` is supposed to take `Object`, not `ParentClass`.

Comment: did you tried this: ChildClass pa2 = (ChildClass) pa; then use pa2.getID();?

Comment: yep, now it works, that was the problem, thanks @Spara

Comment: @ManuelCárdenas So I will make it as an answer for you :)

Comment: @user2357112 It's not Override of the Object.java "equals" method. It's kind of method overloading.

Comment: @Spara: Overloading `equals` (as opposed to overriding) is a very error-prone design decision even if deliberate, and it doesn't sound deliberate here.

Comment: @user2357112 of course it's not good idea to overload equals method! but I just told you that it's not Override and there is no compile error on that :)

Comment: The point we're trying to make is that OP *should* `@Override` it, and should *never* overload it. Overloading `equals` is bad practice, and should not be done, because it will lead to confusing errors.

Comment: @Krease as I told I'm agree with both of you! but I tried to focus on his problem and I didn't make lots of changes to confuse him!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After you check the type of object and ensure that it's instance of `ChildClass` just convert it to `ChildClass` type and use it:

```
public boolean equals(ParentClass pa) {
if (!(pa instanceof ChildClass))
    return false;
ChildClass child = (ChildClass) pa;
boolean sameID = ID.equals(child.getID());
return super.equals(child) && sameID;
}
```

Comment: `equals` is supposed to take `Object`, not `ParentClass`. Please don't propagate the bad part from the OP question

Comment: I'm in fact quite calm, and while you may disagree with it, there's nothing impolite about my statement. It's a bad practice to overload equals, and we, as experienced programmers providing answers, should do our best to teach better practices when the opportunities arise. I'd do the same if any of my work colleagues showed me the original code.

Comment: @Krease of course it's bad idea to overload equals! but I think It's better to just focus on the user's question and try to not make him confuse with lots of changes!

Comment: Overriding `equals` is a fundamental part of programming in Java. Pointing out minor changes to correct bad practices should not be confusing. It's what makes answers on StackOverflow more useful to everyone.

Answer (score -2):

There's a common pattern that's useful to follow when overriding `equals`. I'll provide a version with the corrections here, and outline what those corrections were below:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) { return true; }
    if (!super.equals(o) 
        || o == null 
        || getClass() != o.getClass()) { 
            return false; 
    }
    ChildClass other = (ChildClass) o;
    return this.getID().equals(other.getID());
}
```

First, the stuff you can generally copy-paste between implementations of `equals`:

- Always `@Override` the `equals` method - this will help identify issues where you're accidentally overloading it (same method name, different argument types). Overloading `equals` is a bad practice that will cause problems.
- Start with `==` check - if this passes, no need to waste CPU cycles doing any more logic. Though this is really just a minor optimization, it's a useful best practice.
- If you are extending a class other than `Object`, check for `super` equality.
- Check to make sure the classes are the **same**. Note that this is **not** an `instanceof` check.

  - Remember, `equals` must be symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.
  - If you use `instanceof`, you'll likely run into case where `parent.equals(child) == true` but `child.equals(parent) == false` - that's bad.
  - There are cases where `instanceof` is ok, but checking class equality is safer and more correct most of the time.

Now, the class specific stuff:

- Cast the `Object` parameter to your class type, and compare the ones you care about for equality.

  - Note that the calls on `this` should match the calls on `other` - in your case, I changed both to call `getID()` method. Alternatively, both can refer to the private member `ID` - but they should be consistent.

**Finally, don't forget that `equals` and `hashCode` are a pair - you should always implement them together**.  (I know you didn't specifically ask about it, but I'm pointing it out as it's a common error people make when implementing `equals`)

- If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result. If you only override equals() and not hashCode() your class violates this contract.

I hope this helps you and anyone else with problems implementing `equals`.